# Vue same component inputs doesnt update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I have reused same component at navigation menu and at peoples page

My issue is that when SearchComponent inputs in navigation updates its value Peoples page SearchComponent inputs doesnt update it's value vice versa. How should I do/achieve this in Vue JS. Below are my codes

**SearchComponent**

```
<template>
  <div class="search">
     <input type="text" v-model="name">
     <input type="text" v-model="email">
     <input type="text" v-model="age">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'SearchComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      age: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Navigation**

```
<template>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>
    <SearchComponent />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SearchComponent from './SearchComponent'
export default {
    name: 'NavComponent',
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      age: ''
    }
  },
  components: {SearchComponent}
}
</script>
```

**Peoples Page**

```
<template>
  <div class="persons">
    <SearchComponent />
    <PersonList />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SearchComponent from './SearchComponent'
import PersonList from './PersonList'
export default {
    name: 'PersonsPage',
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      age: ''
    }
  },
  components: {SearchComponent, PersonList}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @Eli, Try this way to share the same object reference for all the instances' data:

```
<template>
  <div class="persons">
    <SearchComponent />
    <PersonList />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SearchComponent from './SearchComponent'
import PersonList from './PersonList'
const personPageData = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      age: ''
    };
export default {
    name: 'PersonsPage',
  data() {
    return personPageData; //Same state object referred by all instances.
  },
  components: {SearchComponent, PersonList}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That’s because each time you use a Vue Component, a [new instance of it is created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#components-demo)

> Since components are reusable Vue instances, they accept the same options as new Vue, such as `data`, `computed`, `watch`, `methods`, and lifecycle hooks. The only exceptions are a few root-specific options like `el`.

So if you want if you want all Instance to be affected as single component Instead, a component’s `data` should not be declared as function but as object instead i.e.

```
data: {
  name: '',
  email: '',
  age: ''
}
```

Instead of

```
data: function () {
  return {
   name: '',
  email: '',
  age: ''
  }
}
```

For which in your case you have defined it as:

```
data() {
return { 
   name: '',
   email: '',
   age: ''
 }
}
```

You can also find more about [Component Reusing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and also [Organizing Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Organizing-Components) and Since **SearchComponent** and **PersonList** component are child of *Peoples Component* you also need to have idea how to pass data from  [Parent Component i.e Peoples to Child components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)

Comment: I tried to use data as an object but Vue returns an error in console saying that data mus be a function

Comment: @PenAndPapers Declare a Global Object outside (in the script) and return the same object reference in the function's return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Those `SearchComponent` even if they are the same component, they are different instances. Each one of them have their own independent data. If you want both to be in sync I'd recommend to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to have a global store that they can use as a source of truth.

Comment: That was I was thinking, but were not allowed to use plugins and stuffs like that for this project. Vuex could have made our lives easier.